# Calling Typescript function from Highcharts load event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to call typescript function `openDialog()` from the `events.load` of highcharts but I am not able to call it. Even though I am using arrow function I am not able to get it. Here is my code :

```
events: {
    load: () => {
       var chart : any = this;
      for (var j in chart.series) {
        var series = chart.series[j];
        for (var i in series.data) {
          ((i) =>{
            var point = series.data[i];
            if (point.graphic) {
              point.graphic.on('click',(e)=>this.openDialog(point.options,'all')
            );
            }
          })(i)
        }
      }
    }
  },


  public openDialog(option,type){
       //Do Something
  }
```

**EDIT**

I have got one [link](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36471) where there are binding `this` with function.

Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: how about using  `load: () => {` instead of `load: function() {`

Comment: The issue here is `this` refers inside the `load` function scope and it does not contains your `openDialog()`, declare `const that = this` before the `load:`, and then replace your `this.openDialog()` with `that.openDialog()`, this should work or can you create a stackblitz demo with minimal code,

Comment: @Kenny oops that was actually a mistake by my end It is arrow function only. Updated the question

Comment: @AkhilAravind is it possible to add inside chart creation ? I think it is not

Comment: Some how I managed to do it once in reactjs, could you please produce a stackblitz demo, with minimal code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: whatever I have given as a code is this only. It's preety much difficult to create stackblitz demo for this

Comment: Could you please check the stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-qabp9m

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have added code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-wh4dhc Still not working. Can you check ?

Comment: You for loop is not working, can you add console in each for loop and check

Comment: @TheHungryDictator where is `graphic` ? As you mention in check `point.graphic`

Comment: @AkhilAravind that's what the issue is. Loops are and functions are only working while you are using it with `function()` but getting error with it since `this` is what the issue is here.

Comment: @Kenny it's used to create graph. the `svg` items

Comment: @TheHungryDictator i was out for lunch, Please check  my solution :)

Comment: @AkhilAravind I got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it worked by this simple change

```
events: {
  load: function(e) {
   var chart : any = e.target; // to get the chart details
  for (var j in chart.series) {
    console.log(j)
    var series = chart.series[j];
    for (var i in series.data) {

      ((i) =>{
        console.log(i)
        var point = series.data[i];
        if (point.graphic) {
          point.graphic.on('click',(e)=>this.openDialog()
        );
        }
      })(i)
    }
  }
  }.bind(this) //binding the parent this to access openDialog function
},


public openDialog(option,type){
   //Do Something
}
```

Here I had to bind this which does not comes from chart. So I have to bind `this` using `.bint(this)` to the load function. And to get the chart details I am using `e.target`. This way I am getting it worked.

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-wh4dhc)**

Answer (score 1):

Check the update code replacing arrow function,

Here assigning chart options has moved to a function, `init(){}` and declared `var that = this;` inside it, also replaced the `()=>{}` with `function()`.

You can check the stackblitz update [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-yls8nh)

```
import {  Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { HighchartsService } from './highcharts.service.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('charts') public chartEl: ElementRef;
  myOptions={};
  constructor(private highcharts: HighchartsService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.init();
    this.highcharts.createChart(this.chartEl.nativeElement, this.myOptions);
  }
  init(){
   var that = this;
   this.myOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      events: {
      load: function(){
      var chart : any = this;
      for (var j in chart.series) {
        var series = chart.series[j];
        for (var i in series.data) {
          ((i) =>{
            var point = series.data[i];
            if (point.graphic) {
              point.graphic.on('click',(e)=>that.openDialog()
            );
            }
          })(i)
        }
      }
      }
    },
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
      name: 'Joe',
      data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
  };
      }

  public openDialog(){
       console.log('open dialog, hey this works here')
  }
}
```

Comment: I have simply `bind(this)` with the `function()` and it started working. Although your code is also working for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work or not, but from my understanding, your this is not pointing to myOptions object and series key is present in myOptions object,

To make this work you should declare `series` outside of myOptions object

```
seriesData = [{
  name: 'John',
  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
  name: 'Jane',
  data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
  name: 'Joe',
  data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}];

 myOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
           load: () => {
              for (var j in this.seriesData) {
                  var series = this.seriesData[j];
                  for (var i in series.data) {
                   .
                   .
                  }
              }
            }
        }
    },

    series: this.seriesData
 }
```

Comment: No it won't work since we want it to be done at each iteration